# AWS S3 bucket image upload error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-admin, bucket, image-upload

I've tried to upload image file to AWS S3 bucket in react-admin.

```
const s3 = new ReactS3Client(s3Config);
const newPictures = params.data.images.rawFile;
const filename = newPictures.name;
const res = await s3.uploadFile(newPictures, filename);
```

I've set the s3Config parameter correctly.
When I run above code, I got the below error.

```
react-aws-s3.js:225 POST https://mazola-prod.s3-website.me-south-1.amazonaws.com/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`
`ypeError: Failed to fetch
    at ReactS3Client.<anonymous> (react-aws-s3.js:225)
    at step (react-aws-s3.js:145)
    at Object.next (react-aws-s3.js:75)
    at react-aws-s3.js:47
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at push../node_modules/react-aws-s3-typescript/dist/react-aws-s3.js.__awaiter (react-aws-s3.js:26)
    at ReactS3Client.uploadFile (react-aws-s3.js:194)
... ... ...
```

Please help me to fix the bug

Comment: Are you sure you want to POST to a `s3-website`?

Comment: yes, I've used below `import ReactS3Client from 'react-aws-s3-typescript'`   `const res = await s3.uploadFile(newPictures, filename);` it doesn't work